# GPG (PGP) decryption in client side web applications

Tags: javascript, web-applications, encryption, pgp, gnupg

How would I be able to decrypt some encrypted data on the client side of a web application?

E.g.

- The data is stored encrypted on the server.
- It was encrypted using a public GPG key.
- The server sends the encrypted to the client.
- The client needs to decrypt it using their local private key.

Assumably I would be able to pass the private key to the browser and use Javascript to decrypt  the data.

Comment: Host proof hosting https://www.passpack.com/blog/2008/03/host-proof-hosting/

Comment: Please see my a little related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30951805/encrypt-on-server-side-and-decrypt-on-client-side

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to stick with JavaScript, then have a look at the LGPL library [OpenPGP.js](http://openpgpjs.org/).

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm coming a bit late to this, but for future reference, there's always an option of using [crypto-browserify](https://github.com/crypto-browserify/crypto-browserify) via [Browserify](http://browserify.org/).

Comment: Does it include OpenPGP?

Comment: No, it doesn't, but there is a library called [openpgp.js](http://openpgpjs.org/) (see [here](https://github.com/openpgpjs/openpgpjs/issues/254) for browserify specifics). It's important to note that, depending on the expected load, it might be beneficial to offload the encryption and decryption to a web worker, to avoid blocking the browser's main UI thread.